# How to linearize this in equilibrium?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, linearization

Consider the pde system

$$
u_t=-uu_x-vu_y+fv-g\cdot (H+c)_x\\
v_t=-uv_x-vv_y-fu-g\cdot (H+c)_y\\
H_t=-(uH)_x-(vH)_y
$$
where $u=u(x,y,t), v=v(x,y,t), H=H(x,y,t)$ and $f\in\mathbb{R}$ is a parameter, $c$ is a constant. $g$ is the gravitational acceleration.

A trivial equilibrium is given by $E=(0,0,H_0)$ with $H_0$ being a constant.

My question is: How do I linearize in this equilibrium? I really have no idea.

Comment: Should the first term in the right-hand side of the second line read $vv_x$ instead of $uv_x$? Just asking because of symmetry concerns.

Comment: No, this is the way I found the equations.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where did you find this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We linearize by dividing $u$, $v$, and $H$ into the following:

$$u(x,y,t)=u_0(x,y)+\epsilon u_1(x,y,t)$$
$$v(x,y,t)=v_0(x,y)+\epsilon v_1(x,y,t)$$
$$H(x,y,t)=H_0(x,y)+\epsilon H_1(x,y,t)$$

where $\epsilon$ is small. Substituting into the above, with $u_0=v_0=0$ and $H_0$ constant, and discarding terms of order $\epsilon^2$ or higher:

$$u_{1,t}=fv_1-g\cdot H_{1,x}$$
$$v_{1,t}=-fu_1-g\cdot H_{1,y}$$
$$H_{1,t}=-H_0(u_{1,x}+v_{1,y})$$

Hopefully that's a simple enough form.

Comment: Is this a general ansatz to linearize in functions? I only know linearizing in an equilibrium $x_0$ by making the ansatz $x=x_0+\Delta x$. Your ansatz looks similar. Or maybe it is even the same?

Comment: Mine is the same as yours, except in my opinion it's easier to work with, as the parts to discard become readily visible.

Comment: Sorry, I do not see why it is the same :D

Comment: Let $\Delta x = \epsilon x_1$.

Comment: We have that $\Delta x=x-x_0$, i.e. the difference. But $\epsilon  x_1$ isn't a difference.

Comment: Yes it is. Since $x=x_0+\epsilon x_1$, we also have that $\epsilon x_1 = x - x_0$.